# PHP output to JS to render as HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, getjson

I have this output that I got from my PHP page:

```
{"schedules":{"Event_Date":"2011-03-12","Meet_Name":"Time Trials ","Duration":"9:00am-12:00pm","Location":"Agoura High School","Address":"28545 Driver Ave","City":"Agoura Hills","State":"CA","Postal":"91301"}}
```

I would like to render this output as HTML using this Javascript code:

```
var serviceURL = "http://localhost/";

var schedules;

$('#Schedule').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
getScheduleList();
});

function getScheduleList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'get_Mobile_Schedule.php', function(data) {
        $('#schedulelist li').remove();
        schedules = data.items;
        $.each(schedules, function(index, item) {
            $('#schedulelist').append('<li><h4>' + item.Event_Date +'</h4>'
                    ); 
        });
        $('#schedulelist').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

But it seems that I cannot get anything to render.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: firebug is good friend , also check that you are sending json headers ,before you echo the string.

Answer (score 2):

`schedules = data.items` - `data` does not contain a property named `items`. You probably want `schedules = data.schedules` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON has an extra '}' at the end. JQuery won't recognize it if it's malformed.

Also, bindings should happen within the jquery 'ready' function. Try this:

```
$(document).ready({function() {
    $('#Schedule').getSced = getScheduleList();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

even if it works for you, try to use this instead

```
'<li><h4>' + item.Event_Date +'</h4></li>'
```

the not closed tag can be a problem.